# Magento - showing categories from 2nd level parent?

Tags: magento, navigation, sidebar

I have the following category structure..

```
Defualt
    - Cat a
        - child a
        - child b
        - child c
        - child d
    - Cat b
        - child a
        - child b
        - child c
```

When you are viewing Category A, or any of it's child categories for example, I would like to show all of the categories in Category A in the left category sidebar, no matter the depth, as long as the page you are in is contained within Category A

The same rule applies for Category B. When you are viewing Category B, it's child categories or any products within the child categories, I would like the child categories from Category B to be shown in the left sidebar at any depth.

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Need a little more information. Do you plan on querying for the data serverside, and only showing those categories, or is using JavaScript to hide/show items OK? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the template: catalog/navigation/category_nav.phtml

```
<div class="block-category-nav">

  <div class="block-content">
    <ol>

    <?php //echo $this->renderCategoriesMenuHtml() // 1. Full categories tree ?>

    <?php // 2. Current category tree
    foreach ($this->getStoreCategories() as $_category){
        if($this->isCategoryActive($_category)) // ...only from active node
            echo $this->drawItem($_category,-1);
    }?>

    <?php /*/ 3. Current subcategories 
    foreach ($this->getCurrentChildCategories() as $_category){
        echo $this->drawOpenCategoryItem($_category);
    }*/?>

    </ol>
  </div>

</div>
```